# What is this number 1 on my Google Chrome icon (Mac)?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, osx-el-capitan

After the latest update (or a very recent one if not the latest; basically it showed up sometime leading up to or including `Version 47.0.2526.111 (64-bit)`, which is what is currently running), the Chrome icon is showing a numeral one in the bottom-right corner (see image below). This doesn't appear to correspond to downloads, as I've cleared the download list on both profiles.  It also doesn't appear to correspond to profile, as the circle with a 1 in it doesn't correspond with either of the profiles (I came across an article stating that the pizza icon that had shown up for someone was corresponding to the user), and it doesn't change based on active window.

Does anyone know what this is for?

[image: Chrome with numeral 1]

Comment: it's supposed to be active downloads...  If you click the icon, and hit "quit", does it ask you about continuing/cancelling downloads?

Comment: That's what I suspected at first, but I couldn't locate any active downloads...but yes, it asked me to cancel, which I did.  I then went ahead and quit Chrome completely, and the number is gone.  Odd.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The number represents active downloads...

Those if you have a transfer pending (or paused, or perhaps corrupted), it may not show up in the download list, yet it's still "active".

Click the Chrome icon, and choose "quit", if you have any pending/active/paused downloads, it will offer you a chance to cancel or continue them.  Cancel them, exit Chrome, and the number overlay should go away.

For more info/discussion perhaps check out [this Google Groups posting](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/rLvwd7iEIa8).

Comment: Rather than quit Chrome, you can just open the Downloads window (Ctrl-J, or ⋮> Downloads) and cancel the downloads that way.

Comment: @dimo414 OP says: "I've cleared the download list on both profiles."

Comment: adding that on macOS, you can cancel a download from the `~/Downloads` folder or dock widget and that will also dismiss the icon notification.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes downloads are suspended because Chrome has deemed the website "suspicious."  These suspended downloads are listed as not complete so a number will pop up on the icon showing how many downloads are not complete.

You can see all your downloads by selecting **Window -> Downloads**. You'll see something like this:
[image]

In my case Chrome thinks that Tumblr is a dangerous website and has suspended downloading an image from there.

If you want to continue downloading the file, click on **Keep** (and confirm when the popup asks you to verify), otherwise click on **Discard** to remove the file from the download list.  This should take care of the distracting numbers in your icon.

Answer (score 1):

There are some applications/websites that don't use the google download function. I had the same issue... quit Chrome (confirmed download cancellation). Then remembered that I had used Whatsapp Web on my Mac on a large video then never seemed to finish downloading. I can recreate the Number in the Dock Icon by reclicking on the Whatsapp video... no worries